# AJAX form executed by onblur OR change event

Tags: ajax, onchange, onblur

I have a form where the user will enter a number into a text field.  Then, select another number from a dropdown menu.  I want the AJAX to execute each time they go from field to field.  This is so that it does a calculation in real-time.

I would imagine the text field would be using "onblur" and the dropdown using "change" or "onchange"...  but how do I write the script to do EITHER depending on which field they are currently on?  Can you set it to do both?

EDIT:  New attempt with new variable labels.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function postData(){
            var widthX = $('#width_str').val();
            var heightX = $('#height_str').val();
            var prodidX = $('#prodid').val();
            var roomX = $('#room_str').val();

            $.post('db_query.php',{widthX:widthX, heightX:heightX, prodidX:prodidX, roomX:roomX},   
                function(data){
                $("#search_results").html(data);
            });
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {postData()});
            $("#room_str").bind('change', function() {postData()});
            $("#width_str").bind('change', function() {postData()});
            $("#height_str").bind('change',function() {postData()});
        });
    </script>
```

Part of the form here....

```
         <form id="lets_search" action="" style="width:400px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" value="<?php echo stripslashes($_GET['prodid']); ?>" name="prodid" id="prodid">

            room name:
            <select name="room_str" id="room_str">
                <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
                <option value="Bathroom">Bathroom</option>
                <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
            </select>
            height:
            <select name="height_str" id="height_str">
                <option value="30">30"</option>
                <option value="31">31"</option>
                <option value="32">32"</option>
                <option value="33">33"</option>
                <option value="34">34"</option>
                <option value="35">35"</option>
                <option value="36">36"</option>
                <option value="37">37"</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            width:
            <select name="width_str" id="width_str">
                <option value="30">30"</option>
                <option value="31">31"</option>
                <option value="32">32"</option>
                <option value="33">33"</option>
                <option value="34">34"</option>
                <option value="35">35"</option>
                <option value="36">36"</option>
                <option value="37">37"</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">
         </form>
```

The php page that processes the data...

```
<?php
include('db_pbconnection.php');

$tax = .06;
$tax2 = 1.06;
$grandtotal = 50;   

$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM price_dimensions WHERE prodid = '".$_POST['prodidX']."' AND height >= '".$_POST['heightX']."' AND width >= '".$_POST['widthX']."' ORDER BY height ASC, width ASC LIMIT 1 ");
echo '<div>';
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '
    <div style="background-color:pink;">
        <div style="clear:both; font-size:18px;">height: '.$data["height"].'</div><br>
        <div style="clear:both; font-size:18px;">width: '.$data["width"].'</div>
        <div style="clear:both; font-size:18px;">unit price: '.$data["price"].'</div>
        <div style="clear:both; font-size:18px;">tax: '.(($data["price"])*($tax)).'</div>
        <div style="clear:both; font-size:18px;">grand total:'.(($data["price"])*($tax2)).'</div>
    </div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can call the AJAX from any area by moving the code into a separate function and binding any event to that function.

```js
function postData(){
    var value = $('#str').val();
    var valueH = $('#strH').val();
    var prodid = $('#prodid').val();

    $.post('db_query.php',{valueH:valueH, value:value, prodid:prodid},   
        function(data){
        $("#search_results").html(data);
    });
    return false;
}

$(function() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {postData()});
    $("#strH").bind('change', function() {postData()});
    $("#str").bind('blur',function() {postData()});
});
```

Comment: oh I see.  So in that bottom area, you could add any sort of "trigger" (if that's the terminology) you'd like, and depending on what the user clicks or does, it fires it off with the corresponding piece of code ... i.e. submit = button...  change = drop down... blur = text field.  Correct?

Comment: You could have an infinite amount of lines in the lower area assigning the `postData()` function to various events (e.g. dropdown change, text blur, etc.). At this point, the page is listening for those events to happen and will call the function when one does. The 'submit', 'change', 'blur' are just the type of events. You could have multiple 'change' events, for example, or change the 'blur' to 'change' for a textbox, without incident. It's just the event you're subscribing to.

Comment: It makes perfect sense.  But it's not working.  My syntax could be wrong since I changed the variable names.  I will edit above and show how I changed it.

Comment: In your new example, you bound `#roomX`, `#widthX`, etc. and it looks like you should be binding `#room_str`, `#width_str`, etc. That should fix it. I tested it locally with a simple alert function instead of jQuery, and it works with that change.